# Unknown error when creating packages with pkgbuild

Tags: macos, installation, pkgbuild

I followed several tutorials-which all appeared to say the same thing-on how to create deployable flat-packages (.pkg) using the OS X system provided `pkgbuild` tool. The packages was always generated just fine. They did, however, not want to be installed.

Running the graphical Apple Installer or the command line interface `installer` aborted the installation early on giving an generic “Unknown error” after prompting for higher permissions.

Hours later after closer investigation I discovered that I could not install other packages either. Not even updates and new installations from the OS X App Store. Why could I not install my own nor any other packages? What was going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer daemon service itself is unresponsive. Force quit the installed program from from the Activity Monitor, or from the command line with `sudo killall installd`.